# Rails - Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick is not installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, imagemagick, minimagick

So I have image uploading to google cloud storage working fine with carrierwave. Now I want to have all images converted to .png using minimagick. I added the mini_magic gem and tested it out on my mac and it works fine. When I deployed the changes and tested it in production I get the error:

`Value Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick is not installed`

I'm using a Google Cloud Publisher VM on the flexible environment. So I connected it via SSH and ran `sudo apt-get install imagemagick`. It finished and it looks like imagemagick installed successfully.

```
root@cs-6908-devshell-vm-5a72c8c9-d84d-4072-a5ba-29d989ab6282-131:/home/user# convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2016-06-01 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC Features: DPC Modules OpenMP
Delegates: bzlib cairo djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png rsvg tiff wmf x xml zlib
```

Problem is that I still get the same error. I've seen this problem in other questions but there were for mac and windows.

Comment: show `gem list magick`

Comment: You've installed graphicsmagick, yes?

Comment: @CDub I thought it needed either ImageMagic or GraphicsMagick so I only installed ImageMagic

Comment: @CDub I added GraphicsMagick just for the sake of it and I still get the error.